# Why is JAVA process requiring a windows domain user in stead of a local user?

Tags: windows, powershell, java, scheduled-tasks

I have powershell script that executes a JAR-file (in `$3DjarPath`) using:

`Invoke-Expression '& $JavaPath -Xmx512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -splash: -jar $3DjarPath backuprepo -repo $repo -o "$($BKP_Dir)$($BKP_Name)" -f'`

I can run this script using my local user without problems.

However, when trying to run the script using a scheduler service, the script will not run successfully. My supplier says the scheduler service must be run using a domain user, but I have no AD.

The scheduler service is now run under local user that has all rights.

I also tried to run the script using the TaskScheduler. Same thing. No result.

Why is it not running? and is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a PowerShell ExecutionPolicy issue. Add `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` argument to your PowerShell task.

[image]